# Google spreadsheet =IMPORTXML result is blank

Tags: selenium, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to import the buy price on https://www.zebpay.com/#chart site

I tried following different cell formulas but result is blank:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.zebpay.com/#chart",".//*[@id='buy']")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.zebpay.com/#chart","//a/span[2]")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.zebpay.com/#chart","//span[@id='buy']")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.zebpay.com/#chart","//div[@id='bitlabel']/a/span[2]")
```

I also tried above things removing #chart.

Can someone help with solution?
Also is there easy tool to find Xpath with works with sheet, I used selenium IDE in above case.

Comment: Your xpath is correct

Answer (score 0):

for locateing webElement you can use [ranorex chrome extension](https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/instrumentation-wizard/google-chrome) [link to download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ranorex-automation/egdlgaljianpgdlmfijpphbadibfncdm?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

found Bypass solution:
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr")
Zebpay hav provided API: https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr

After getting data then it can be processed further to get exact value for calculation.